# access bridge explorer not listing the checkboxes in JMeter window

Tags: java, bridge, ui-spy

I am trying to automate JMeter using Java Access Bridge for learning purposes. Am using pyjab which is a python wrapper for JAB. I have installed access bridge explorer to inspect the elements in JMeter and get their properties. However, there are some checkboxes that is not displayed in the root pane in the access bridge explorer but the properties are shown when highlighted.

When i try to click it am getting the error that element is not available in root node.

[image: checkbox am trying to click]

its not listed in here.

[image]

Thanks for your help...